# Issue deploying Flask app to Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I want to update an app i have on heroku from a project i worked on over a month ago.

I just want to push my new .py app to it. But i get the following error when using `git push heroku master`

> remote: -----> Failed to detect app matching https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz buildpack

My file structure is:

[image]

Procfile is `web: gunicorn app:app`

As far as im aware, having a current require.emts.txt and pushing should be all i need?

How can i trouble shoot this?

Here is the terminal print:

[image]

local web screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Could you add the contents of Procfile to your post?

Comment: I have added the file contents

Comment: Does the application run locally with `heroku local web`?

Comment: What actions to I need to take to confirm this sorry?

Comment: Try to run the `heroku local web` command. You will need to install the [Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) if you haven't already.

Comment: with my virtual env activated or outside it?

Comment: After activating the virtualenv.

Comment: updating OP with screenshot...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148165/discussion-between-bovarysme-and-jwarris91).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by doing a git commit `$ git commit -am "descrip"` before doing a git push `$ git push heroku master`, just doing a git push caused conflict with file recognition